# Get and add values from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Here is my Hash:

```
{"graph"=>[{"1"=>16, "2"=>44, "3"=>53, "4"=>53, "5"=>80, "6"=>71, "7"=>63, "8"=>54, "9"=>53, "10"=>44, "11"=>76, "12"=>82, "13"=>66, "14"=>59, "15"=>64, "16"=>39, "17"=>19, "18"=>14, "19"=>5, "20"=>6, "21"=>5, "22"=>7, "23"=>6, "24"=>7}]}
```

I'm trying to get the values of each and add them together. The long and incorrect way would be to get each value and add them together like so:

```
first_number = json["graph"][0]["1"]
second_number = json["graph"][0]["2"]
```

How can I simplify this to get that total count?

Comment: So you want a total sum of the entire array?

Comment: Yes, so like `16 + 44 + 53` and so on to get the total of all 24 values

Comment: For accuracy, your "JSON" is not JSON, it's a Ruby hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need is the sum of those values...

```
json['graph'][0].values.inject{|sum,val| sum+val}
```

If you are using rails, you have the option to use the `sum` method instead:

```
json['graph'][0].values.sum
```

`inject` takes a given block and executes the block once for every element in the Array.  `val` is the current value being evaluated, and `sum` is the value that was last returned from the block.  Thus, if you add the two every time the block runs, and return the result, you will get a sum of your values at the end of execution.

You can see the documentation here:  http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject

Comment: @nzifnab it will be more helpful if you describe how this work

Comment: I saw you did `.sum` originally, before changing to `inject`. They both yield the same result, so is there a significant difference?

Comment: `sum` is not a method of `Array` UNLESS you are using Rails, because `ActiveSupport` adds it